# Is this cron * 13 */3 * * not valid for airflow?

Tags: cron, airflow

We recently switched to airflow 1.10.3 and facing that the job is not getting scheduled if day of the month(*/3 here) is divided by any integer other than 1. Is this the version issue or airflow dropped it support? Surprisingly * 13 1-30/3 * * works.

Comment: Suggesting migrating over to a networking / administration board.  It's a valid question, but not really a programming one.